Bluetooth stopped working on Kubuntu 24.04
It worked on 22.04 just fine. My computer is Sony Vaio Duo 13. Idk how to check what specific Bluetooth it is other than that it is Broadcom.
I can provide more details just tell me what commands to use on the terminal. I can't go back to 22.04.
I updated 24.04 to the latest 6.8 kernel from Ubuntu. It made the Bluetooth show up at least, it could find devices and connect, but it disconnects after a few seconds and audio (works after systemctl restart bluetooth) is really choppy.
Basically rendered it useless. This so strange that a new version would break something so basic on an LTS release. So disappointed.
[    0.000091] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.068708] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.354161] ACPI: thermal: [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip points!
[    3.762775] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.762820] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.762823] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.762898] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.762903] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.762912] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.846743] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.846753] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.846756] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.846785] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.846788] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.846811] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.846864] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.847776] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    3.847799] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.847802] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    3.847822] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    4.253616] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 84
[    4.254136] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x0f
[    4.255386] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4324B3
[    4.255393] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4324B3 (002.004.006) build 0000
[    4.264941] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4324B3 'brcm/BCM4324B3.hcd' Patch
[    4.858201] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x0f
[    4.859616] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43241B4 Class1 IPAAGB
[    4.859621] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4324B3 (002.004.006) build 0112
[    5.025034] brcmfmac mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
[    5.202497] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4324/5 wl0: Jul 17 2013 07:36:07 version 6.10.197.71 (r412987) FWID 01-882d2634
[    6.648362] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.648372] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.648378] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.660589] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   10.363647] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   10.363659] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   10.363669] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1994.502528] brcmfmac mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
[ 1994.655592] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4324/5 wl0: Jul 17 2013 07:36:07 version 6.10.197.71 (r412987) FWID 01-882d2634
[ 5493.844464] brcmfmac mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
[ 5493.999804] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4324/5 wl0: Jul 17 2013 07:36:07 version 6.10.197.71 (r412987) FWID 01-882d2634
[ 7178.840297] brcmfmac mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
[ 7178.994226] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4324/5 wl0: Jul 17 2013 07:36:07 version 6.10.197.71 (r412987) FWID 01-882d2634
[15641.122386] brcmfmac mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
[15641.277245] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4324/5 wl0: Jul 17 2013 07:36:07 version 6.10.197.71 (r412987) FWID 01-882d2634
[20805.550122] brcmfmac mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
[20805.703429] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4324/5 wl0: Jul 17 2013 07:36:07 version 6.10.197.71 (r412987) FWID 01-882d2634
[23429.559123] brcmfmac mmc0:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
[23429.714177] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4324/5 wl0: Jul 17 2013 07:36:07 version 6.10.197.71 (r412987) FWID 01-882d2634


Btw I tried installing newer and older kernels, it didn't work on them at all.

Please do not use comments to add info to the question, edit the question. Please add what kernel you are using and what kernels you have tried.

Use the USB and use "Try Kubuntu" see if your Bluetooth is working.

Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
